# Unique SMS sender id?

Tags: sms

I want to build an app that send SMS to people. However, I want my users to know that the SMS comes from the app and nothing else so they can't fake it. Is there a way to guarantee that the sender ID is unique to my app?

It seems that sending a SMS by phone is with a unique SENDER ID for each phone number.
But, from what I read, I don't think it is the case when sending a SMS through a web gateway.
Is this correct? I am not an expert in mobile phone security.

Of course, I am willing to pay the price for a unique sender id, if such thing is possible.

Regards,
Pascal

Comment: OK i did some research and SMS spoofing seems to be a way to do this. However, it seems illegal... any advice?
http://www.smsspoofing.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Sender ID" is called the OADC code and some (depending on your location) SMS gateways will indeed allow you to set this to pretty much anything you like, meaning its probably not a good idea to rely on it as absolute proof of origin.

You could perhaps include some item of data in the message body itself that only you and they know?

Comment: Thanks for the details, I will talk with my partner about this. Providing data might be a good solution.